# Python: easiest way to flatten a tupple containing another tupple from a function

Tags: python, tuples, unpack

My code is like this:

```
def f1():
    return 2, 3

def f2():
    return 1, f1()
```

I can do:

```
a, (b, c) = f2()
```

I want to do:

```
a, b, c = f2()
```

All the solutions I could find require using a lot of insane parenthesis/brackets, or creating an identity function to use `*` operator. I would like to only modify f2().

Is there something simpler?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using `1, f2()`, use tuple concatenation:

```
def f2():
    return (1,) + f1()
```

As mentioned in a comment, you could also do this:

```
def f2():
    x,y = f1()
    return 1, x, y
```

You could also do this:

```
def f2():
    return (lambda *args: args)(1, *f1())
```

That is a little long, but it has an advantage over the `x,y = f1()` solution because this way `f1()` can return a tuple with any number of elements.

Comment: Alternatively, `x, y = f1(); return 1, x, y`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Very true.  I have added that.